# Realtime JSON data to panda dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have been trying to normalize my JSON file which I retrieved from Firebase Realtime Database, and turn it into a python panda data-frame but I keep getting everything as a row.

my JSON file is structured as following:

```
{
    “Device 1” {
        “ID-1”{
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
        “ID-2”{
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
        “ID-3”{
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
        “ID-4”{
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
    }
    “Device 2" {
        “ID-1”{
            “key”:  value
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
        “ID-2”{
            “key”:  value
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
        “ID-3”{
            “key”:  value
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
        “ID-4”{
            “key”:  value
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
    }
    “Device 3" {
        “ID-1”{
            “key”:  value
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
        “ID-2”{
            “key”:  value
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
        “ID-3”{
            “key”:  value
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
        “ID-4”{
            “key”:  value
            “key”:  value
            “time”: xxx
        }
    }
}
```

what I am trying to do is have each device in a separate table, with the ID as a column alongside the values listed below it, like this:

Device 1 table:

| ID | key 1 | key 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id value | value | value |

Device 2 table:

| ID | key 1 | key 2 | key 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id value | value | value | value |

Device 3 table:

| ID | key 1 | key 2 | key 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id value | value | value | value |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Since each Device is a table, I'll split them into individual dataframes. We can always unite them later if need be.

I'll suppose you have your JSON data in a dict called `devices`

```
import pandas as pd

dataframes = []
for device, id_data in devices.items():
  rows = []
  for row_id, values in id_data.items():
    values["id"] = row_id
    rows.append(values)
  dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(rows))
```